# Implementing a function that steadily expands a dataframe

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe

I would like to point out my problem with following example:

Imagine a dataframe with two vectors x1 and y1.

```
x1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
df <- data.frame(x1, y1)
```

Now I want to create two new variables based on x1 and y1 within df.

```
df$x2 <- df$x1 + df$y1
df$y2 <- df$y1 + 1
```

I want to repeat this step n times, so that a constantly expanding dataframe is emerging (here for example n = 11):

```
df$x3 <- df$x2 + df$y2
df$y3 <- df$y2 + 1
#.
#.
#.
#df$x10 <- df$x9 + df$y9
#df$y10 <- df$y9 + 1
#df$x11 <- df$x10 + df$y10
#df$y11 <- df$y10 + 1
```

Obviously, doing that manually is no problem at all. Since I want to do this procedure with a high number of "n", an automated approach would be much more effective. Unfortunately, I do not know how to code a repeating procedure like that, which always adds a "+1" to specific variable names (here step by step x_i+1 and y_i+1). I would be very grateful for any help implementing such an automated function, which uses an argument "n" (number of repetitive loops) to peform the procedure described above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way using a `for` loop. The main idea of this solution is that we can create variable names and refer to them using the `data[col_name]` selection method.

```
to_n <- 11

for(i in 2:to_n){
  prev_x_name <- paste0('x', i-1)
  prev_y_name <- paste0('y', i-1)

  x_name <- paste0('x', i)
  y_name <- paste0('y', i)

  df[x_name] <- df[prev_x_name] + df[prev_y_name]

  df[y_name] <- df[prev_y_name] + 1

}

#   x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4 ...
# 1  1  1  2  2  4  3  7  4 ...
# 2  2  1  3  2  5  3  8  4 ...
# 3  3  1  4  2  6  3  9  4 ...
```